# Hilt: Multiple Application Classes Extending BaseApp for Different App Stores with minifyEnabled True

Tags: android, dagger-hilt, android-obfuscation

I am developing an Android application that targets two different app stores: Google Play Store and Baidu App Store. To configure the application properly for both stores, I've created two separate custom Application classes, both of which extend an abstract class named `BaseApp`. These custom Application classes are annotated with `@HiltAndroidApp`.

While the configuration works fine in the debug build, I am encountering an issue when building the release version with `minifyEnabled` set to `true`. The error message is as follows:

App must extend android.app.Application [Instantiatable]

```
<application android:name=".GooglePlayApp">
```

This error suggests that the Application class extending `BaseApp` for the Google Play Store version is not recognized as extending `android.app.Application`.

I need help resolving this issue while keeping `minifyEnabled` set to `true` for release builds to optimize APK size and enhance security. Has anyone encountered a similar situation or have insights on how to address this issue with minification enabled?

Comment: You have to extend BaseApp class and make a class and apply it to Application tag in androidmanifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

try to exclude the GoogleApp BiduApp and BaseApp classes from the proguard obfuscation.
following is an example on how to exclude:

```
-keep class com.example.myapp.BaseApp
-keep class com.example.myapp.GoogleApp
-keep class com.example.myapp.BiduApp
```

place this rules in proguard-rules.pro file

Answer (score 0):

@daya-a-l your suggestion didn’t work properly however I got the idea.

to configure Proguard for Google Play, Baidu, and the base module, I organized the Proguard rules as follows:

**Google Play Proguard (`proguard-rules-googleplay.pro`):**

```
-keep class com.example.myapp.BaseApp
-keep class com.example.myapp.GoogleApp
```

**Baidu Proguard (proguard-rules-baidu.pro):**

```
-keep class com.example.myapp.BaseApp
-keep class com.example.myapp.BaiduApp
```

**Base Module Proguard (proguard-rules-base.pro):**

```
-keep class com.example.myapp.BaseApp
```

This setup effectively configures Proguard for multiple app store versions, ensuring the necessary classes are preserved as required.